# Collectd not working on SUSE Linux

Tags: linux, opensuse, suse, collectd

This is the first time I am working with SUSE Linux Enterprise Server and collectd.
The following steps I have performed in order to work with collectd.

1. Downloaded rpm package from [link](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:/Factory/standard/x86_64/collectd-5.5.2-1.1.x86_64.rpm)
2. Installed `make`
3. Installed rpm package
4. executed `./configure` for collectd
5. executed `make` for collectd
6. executed `make install` for collectd
7. changed `collectd.conf` accordingly.
8. executed `sudo service collectd start`

After running this command I am getting the following error :

```
/etc/init.d/collectd: line 13: /etc/init.d/functions: No such file or directory
```

What I am doing wrong.
How to overcome this problem.

Also some of the plugins are not installed , I am getting dependency error.How to install all the plugins correctly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

the function "/etc/init.d/functions" do not exist in SuSe. i think do no need this line, you can comment from init.d/collectd and try if work normally.

more detail of init.d/functions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9314/no-such-file-or-directory-etc-init-d-functions

Comment: I tried this but I faced some other issues.Finally I have installed it using zypper.